# how to replace double backslash with a single one

Tags: c#

I want "PRR\17-18\12" to be PRR\17-18\12

I Have tried below ways but its not working

DepositCode.Replace("\\", "\");
DepositCode.Replace(@"\", @"\");

someone please help

Comment: "it's not working" doesn't really help. "It doesn't compile" would do. Better still is "I get 'unrecognised escape sequence' when I have `"\"`".

Comment: There is no double backslashes in your exmaple

Comment: Please bother to use the search next time. When searching for the exact question title, there are **a lot** of results…

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like that;

```
DepositCode= DepositCode.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
```